# Getstream Chat Documentation for Attachments & Actions / How to make clickable predefined answers?

Tags: react-native, chat, getstream-io

I am not able to find Stream Chat React-Native documentation for Actions or I am not using what I found correct :-)

I am able to find a message example like:

```
    {
      'text': 'Wonderful! Thanks for asking.',
      'attachments': [
        {
          'type': 'form',
          'title': 'Select your account',
          'actions': [
            {
              'name': 'account',
              'text': 'Checking',
              'style': 'primary',
              'type': 'button',
              'value': 'checking'
            },
            {
              'name': 'account',
              'text': 'Saving',
              'style': 'default',
              'type': 'button',
              'value': 'saving'
            },
            {
              'name': 'account',
              'text': 'Cancel',
              'style': 'default',
              'type': 'button',
              'value': 'cancel'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Pushing this message result in a OK rendering in the client.
[Image: Message in chat client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjNbA.png)

However, the React-Native client throws an error when clicking any of the 3 buttons.

The error I get is:

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   Error: StreamChat error code 4: RunMessageAction failed with error: "invalid or disabled command ``"

I have found some references to documentation like this:

> Actions in combination with attachments can be used to build commands.

But the link does not end up describing anything about Commands.

Anyone have any tip. E.g. like a link to some documentation describing how to make **clickable predefined answers work**? :-D

Comment: What are you using for your action handler? As per
https://getstream.github.io/stream-chat-react-native/#!/AttachmentActions/1